# Get rid of Error Function: How to get rid of sequential appearances of error function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

We have a function as

```
e[t_] :=(E^(-t^2)) Cos[0.1 t]
```

and we must evaluate below integration (However I used the variable `x` here, I just want to calculate the integration and `x` is a local variable)

```
a[t_] := Integrate[e[x], {x, 0, t}]
```

the final results is `a[t]`. That it will be of the form:

```
(0. + 2.91163*10^-40 I) (1. Erfi[9.68227 - (0. + 0.00294353 I) t] -   1. Erfi[9.68227 + (0. + 0.00294353 I) t])
```

As it shown, in this result, Error function will appear.
But we have to use of `a[t]` in next our calculation. Actually, we have to evaluate the `p[t_, \[Tau]_]:=Integrate[a[x],{x,t-\[Tau],t}]`
.

For this reason we should have a more clear form of `a[t]` In which there should be no error function. How can we receive the `a[t]` in the absence of Error function? Are there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: The error function is a standard higher transcendental function, so it should be considered a "clear form."  Further it cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.  Unless the error functions cancel each other out (there are identities after all), I do not see how you are going to get rid of it.

Comment: You are right, It is completely rational. The problem was not aroused of Error Function, it was related to some negligible imaginary parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear why you believe that there is a problem with the presence of the error function in `a[t]`.

```
e[t_] = E^(-t^2) Cos[t/10];

a[t_] = Integrate[e[x], {x, 0, t}];
```

`a[t]` is readily integrated

```
 p[t_, tau_] = Integrate[a[x], {x, t - tau, t}]
```

> (1/(80*E^(1/400)))*    (20*(E^(1/20 - I*t)^2 + 
>              E^(1/20 + I*t)^2 - 
>              E^(1/20 + I*(t - tau))^2 - 
>              E^(1/20 - I*t + I*tau)^2) + 
>         Sqrt[Pi]*((-1 + 20*I*t)*
>                Erfi[1/20 - I*t] + 
>              (-1 - 20*I*t)*Erfi[
>                  1/20 + I*t] + 
>              (1 + 20*I*t - 20*I*tau)*
>                Erfi[1/20 + I*(t - tau)] + 
>              (1 - 20*I*t + 20*I*tau)*
>                Erfi[1/20 - I*t + I*tau]))

`p[t, tau]` can be evaluated. `Chop` can be used to remove any negligible imaginary component due to numerical noise.

```
p[2., 1.]
```

> 0.8408887255235893 + 0.*I

```
% // Chop
```

> 0.840889

```
Table[
  {t, tau, p[t, tau] // Chop},
  {t, -4., 4., 2.}, {tau, -4., 4., 2.}] //
 Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {{-4., -4., 3.03855}, {-4., -2., 1.76719}, {-4., 0., 0}, {-4., 
>     2., -1.76803}, {-4., 4., -3.53606}, {-2., -4., 0}, {-2., -2., 
>     1.27137}, {-2., 0., 0}, {-2., 2., -1.76719}, {-2., 
>     4., -3.53521}, {0., -4., -3.03855}, {0., -2., -1.27137}, {0., 0., 0}, {0., 
>     2., -1.27137}, {0., 
>     4., -3.03855}, {2., -4., -3.53521}, {2., -2., -1.76719}, {2., 0., 0}, {2., 
>     2., 1.27137}, {2., 4., 0}, {4., -4., -3.53606}, {4., -2., -1.76803}, {4., 
>     0., 0}, {4., 2., 1.76719}, {4., 4., 3.03855}}

`p[t, tau]` can also be readily plotted.

```
Plot3D[p[t, tau], {t, -10, 10}, {tau, -10, 10},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"t", "tau", "p(t, tau)"})]
```

[image]

As expected from looking at the plot

```
p[t, tau] == p[-t, -tau] // Simplify
```

> True

Comment: +1. But I think the `0. I` is not from numerical noise, but because the numerical type used in the computation is a machine/floating-point `Complex`, which is displayed with `+ 0. I` when the imaginary part is zero.

Comment: OK. Thanks a bunch. I think I had not recognized that the source of the problem. Maybe it arouses of imaginary part of the function. I think 'chop' will help.

Comment: If there has been remained a little question but there would be not a suitable space in this comment place, How can be asked?

Comment: Initiate a new question, just make sure that it differs from the one above.

Comment: Approximately, it needs to the above information. As a matter of fact, I have to use 'p' in other calculations. It means 'p' must be as a parameter not directly as a numeric. the final step is just an integration of a function of 'p' and 'a' (Which is absent here). Every thing is ok with 'p' and 'a'. But that Integration (containing functions of 'p' and 'a') will be gotten stuck. I so much tried to find what is the problem but I could not find any answer or key! Moreover, I can't understand should I substitute CHOP in a very step to the final or should I do that just to the final step?

Comment: `Chop` only works with numeric values. Your comment is too vague to offer any advice.

Comment: Nowadays p[2., 1.] is not that accurate. Instead use p[2, 1] // N